# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'

Tags: python, bar-chart, seaborn

I am plotting a barplot using the `seaborn.barplot` method. The plotting is going through fine. When I am trying to add text on above the bars for better explanation using text method I am running into above mentioned issue.

Below is the code I have tried. With this code I am getting plot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqH7C.png) but i need plot like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/830uz.png)

where values displayed at top of bar are the raised_amount_in_millions value

Here is my code

```
 groupedvalues=master_frame_backup1.groupby('funding_round_type')['raised_amount_in_millions'].mean().reset_index()

 #groupedvalues
 plt.figure(figsize=(30,8))
 pal = sns.color_palette("Greens_d", len(groupedvalues))
 rank = groupedvalues["raised_amount_in_millions"].argsort().argsort() 
 g=sns.barplot(x='funding_round_type',y='raised_amount_in_millions',data=groupedvalues, palette=np.array(pal[::-1])[rank])
 for index, row in groupedvalues.iterrows():
     g.text(row.funding_round_type, row.raised_amount_in_millions," "+str(row.raised_amount_in_millions), color='black', ha="center")

  plt.show()
```

But I am running into above mentioned error. Any help?

Here is the error stack

Here is the error stack
Error in callback .post_execute at 0x00000211F5EB2378> (for post_execute):
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 109, in post_execute
    draw_all()

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_pylab_helpers.py", line 132, in draw_all
    f_mgr.canvas.draw_idle()

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1899, in draw_idle
    self.draw(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 402, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1649, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py", line 2610, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 709, in draw
    bbox, info, descent = textobj._get_layout(renderer)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 286, in _get_layout
    key = self.get_prop_tup(renderer=renderer)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 871, in get_prop_tup
    x, y = self.get_unitless_position()

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 853, in get_unitless_position
    x = float(self.convert_xunits(self._x))

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 186, in convert_xunits
    return ax.xaxis.convert_units(x)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1530, in convert_units
    ret = self.converter.convert(x, self.units, self)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py", line 53, in convert
    unit.update(values)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py", line 341, in **call**
    return printer(obj)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py", line 244, in 
    png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py", line 128, in print_figure
    fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2049, in print_figure
    **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 510, in print_png
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 402, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1649, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py", line 2610, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 709, in draw
    bbox, info, descent = textobj._get_layout(renderer)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 286, in _get_layout
    key = self.get_prop_tup(renderer=renderer)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 871, in get_prop_tup
    x, y = self.get_unitless_position()

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 853, in get_unitless_position
    x = float(self.convert_xunits(self._x))

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 186, in convert_xunits
    return ax.xaxis.convert_units(x)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1530, in convert_units
    ret = self.converter.convert(x, self.units, self)

File "C:\Users\mmajgaon.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py", line 53, in convert
    unit.update(values)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'

Comment: Show the error stacktrace as well.

Comment: Updated error stack in question

Comment: What you will need to do is provide a [mcve] of the problem, such that people can investigate it. That is, there needs to be a code inside the question that if run produces the same error. Also see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)